# Wi-Fi количество полос и пространственных потоков

Tags: android, wifi, android-ndk

По проекту необходимо получить от чипсета девайса информацию о количестве количество полос и пространственных потоков.

1. полосы подразумеваются не `2.4GHz` И `5GHZ`(запросить есть ли `5` можно из `WiFiInfo`) а непосредственно в коридоре `2.4GHz-2.5GHz` (так как ширина `25MHz` то с достаточным промежутком может быть максиvум `3`)
2. Пространственные потоки. это уже к `MIMO` (`Multiple Input Multiple Output`). Вроде как на сегодня `4х4` максимум а то и `2х2` для мобильных.

буду благодарен хотя бы за способ найти хотя бы один из параметров